# Cannot connect to MongoDB running in local Docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have this command to start MongoDB in a container:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 --name cdt-mongo mongo
```

this is from these docs:

https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

I actually think the

```
-p 27017:27017
```

is superfluous. anyway.

Locally, I run the container in one terminal, and then in another terminal I issue the mongo command, and I get:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-05-02T11:27:22.864-0700 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-05-02T11:27:22.866-0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

anybody know why I cannot connect to mongodb running in the container?

Comment: Firstly, you have `-d` and `--rm`, and [according to the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d), this is not allowed.

Comment: I can not reproduce with your commands, what is the `docker logs containerId` output?

Comment: Have you checked the mongo container's logs, to see if it is running smoothly or not?

Comment: @MattClark thanks, good catch, but that's not the root problem

Comment: Thanks all, even if it's not running as a daemon, I have the same problem. I have removed both the -d and -rm flags. Same problem persists. When I run the container without daemon flag, I get "2017-05-02T18:38:24.665+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017"....so it should be listening on the expected port right?

Comment: You run Docker in vanilla Linux or using docker machine?

Comment: on macos, using docker machine

Comment: ehh, I figured it out, need to use the IP address of the docker-machine VM I guess, instead of localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because I am on MacOS, I should not connect to

```
localhost:27017
```

but instead use the host/ip address of the docker-machine VM

```
HOST=$(docker-machine ip)
```

and then connect to it like so:

```
mongo --host $HOST
```

Comment: just an observation, you don't need to use docker-machine anymore, you can use the native docker, so you would be able to use localhost

Comment: thanks, that would be great - do you have a link to that? I don't how to find info on how to use Docker on MacOS w/o docker-machine.

Comment: I guess this is good enough: https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/

Comment: If you go to their official website https://www.docker.com/community-edition all tutorials will now be using the native Docker, as it's not Beta anymore